# gps not getting user location

Tags: android

I am trying to get the current user location (latitude and longitude ) but `onLocationChanged` method is not getting called 
but other methods like public void onProviderDisabled(String provider). Please help, what can be the problem ? 
I have a class:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.lbs;   

import android.app.Activity;   
import android.os.Bundle;   

 import android.app.Activity;     

 import android.content.Context;     

 import android.location.Location;     

 import android.location.LocationListener;     

 import android.location.LocationManager;     

 import android.os.Bundle;     

 import android.view.View;     

 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;     

 import android.widget.Button;     

 import android.widget.Toast;     



 public class LbsGeocodingActivity extends Activity {     



     private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters     

     private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds     



     protected LocationManager locationManager;     



     protected Button retrieveLocationButton;     



     @Override    

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     




     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

     setContentView(R.layout.main);     



     retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);     



     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);     



     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(     

             LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,      

             MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,      

             MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,     

             new MyLocationListener()     

     );     



 retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     

         @Override    

         public void onClick(View v) {     

             showCurrentLocation();     

         }     

 });             



 }         



 protected void showCurrentLocation() {     



     Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);     



     if (location != null) {     

         String message = String.format(     

                 "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",     

                 location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()     

         );     

         Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,     

                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     

     }     



 }        



 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {     



     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {     

         String message = String.format(     

                 "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",     

                 location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()     

         );     

         Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     

     }     



     public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {     

         Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Provider status changed",     

                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     

     }     



     public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {     
         Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,     

                 "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",     

                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     

     }     



     public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {     

         Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,     

                 "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",     

                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     

     }   
 }   
 }
```

Comment: have stimulated a gps coordinates to the emulator through ddms or the telnet command..

Comment: Hi dinesh i am trying it on device samsung galexy s othe methods are getting called bt when i press button a icon shows that gps is searching bt it dosent show any info

Comment: did it worked fine in the emulator.... if yes then check for the internet connection and also check whether gps is enabled... And also check whether the gps coordinates is hooked...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
public static Context mContext;
private double latitude, longitude;
 public LocationManager mLocManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext=this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homelayout);


    mLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            this);
    mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);
    locationUpdate();
    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                DefaultDisplay.class));

                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonProfile))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                MyProfile.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","MyProfile");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonNotifications))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                ShowAllNotificationActiviry.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","ShowAllNotificationActiviry");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonFavorites))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                FavoritesActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","FavoritesActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

            ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonMore))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                MoreListActivity.class));
                }
            });

}

public void locationUpdate()
{
    CellLocation.requestLocationUpdate();
}


public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                + obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    GUIStatics.latitude=location.getLatitude();
    GUIStatics.longitude= location.getLongitude();
    Log.v("Test", "IGA" + "Lat" + latitude + "   Lng" + longitude);
    //mLocManager.r

    getAddress(latitude, longitude);
    if(location!=null)
    {

    mLocManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Lat" + latitude + "   Lng" + longitude,
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
     if(arg1 == 
            LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE) { 
                                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
            "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        } 
                        else if(arg1== LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE) { 
                                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
            "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        } 

}
```

}
This is the my code i am using this for getting user current location.
Read it carefully the check what the mistake you have done in your code.
and also check all the permission in mainfest file related to gps.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I hope this is help.

Comment: Hi DynamicMind i created the code and it is working fine in emulator when i pass latitude and longitude it shows it in the log bt when i try it on device it it shows the icon of gps searching but didnt show in log code is

Comment: i ran the application in bebug mode and it shows me that the methon in not getting called

Comment: i am getting updates as 06-02 12:30:10.504: INFO/GpsLocationProvider(2474): requestRefLocation: gsm_cell = [41022,6733740] 06-02 12:30:10.504: INFO/GpsLocationProvider(2474): requestRefLocation: mcc = 404 mnc = 22                                                                                06-02 12:34:50.293: DEBUG/gps_BRCM(2474): on_location_cb() : lat(18.608823), lon(73.713734), flags(0x00000000), accuracy(1669.000000)
06-02 12:34:50.293: DEBUG/gps_BRCM(2474): on_satellite_cb(num_svs : 0 used_in_fix_mask : 0x00000000)

Comment: Please check it on real device if any problem then tell me because i have check it on real device.

Comment: ya m checking it on samsung galexy s and its not displaying anything did u saw log i posted ? dnt know why it is not working  the method is not getting called

Comment: on my logcat i can see the that it is finding latitude and longitude bt method is not getting called

Comment: In this case tow possibility. 1) It may be possible gps not available on that place so check it out side. 2)May be not getting right context of the application. 3)For resolving these think you should put all the code in Launcher activity it may be solve.

Answer (score 0):

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters

change this to 0 ....

Answer (score 0):

Just extends the GpsStatus.Listener in your activity.
like as following: 
ublic class MyActivity implements LocationListener,
        GpsStatus.Listener

and check your permission: