# Android Geo Location App (Process.com.getgeolocation) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, geolocation

I am writing an android app for detecting user Geo Location. I am testing this app on HTC Android Device. When i am trying to get user location i am getting this message and application stopped.

```
The Applicatiion myappname (Process.com.getgeolocation) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes i have got success in getting user location in Android and i have already given the answer of this type question here the link for getting it.

[gps not getting user location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210523/gps-not-getting-user-location/6210689#6210689)

compare your code with my code and check it what the mistake in your code.
I hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: Thank U.. did u tested this app on Live Device ?

Comment: Yes i have already tested it on real device lot of time it is working fine.